# Websocket server to send continuous stream to client after establishing connection once

Tags: c++, websocket, server

1) Am quite new to c++ and websockets. I have a c++ websocket server. I want to send contineous stream to client after establishing connection once.

2) the clients can be multiple after first exchange the server should continue to write to client.

3) what I did give timeout error after some time.

I tried putting write in loop, which migth be wrong but still gave it a shot. 
It gives timeout error.

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Echoes back all received WebSocket messages
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream> ws_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    boost::asio::io_context::strand strand_;
    list <string> m_sendQueue;
    int time = duration_cast<seconds>((system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())).count();
    std::string contents = "message from server..." + std::to_string(time) ;
    beast::flat_buffer write_buffer;


    std::thread timerThread;

public:



    explicit
    session(tcp::socket&& socket,boost::asio::io_context::strand strand)
            : ws_(std::move(socket)),
              strand_(strand){

       // boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_{ioc_.get_executor()};
      // boost::asio::io_context::executor_type executor = strand_.get_inner_executor();
       // boost::asio::io_context& refIO = executor.context();
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run()
    {


        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
                websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                        beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
                [](websocket::response_type& res)
                {
                    res.set(http::field::server,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                            " websocket-server-async");
                }));

        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_accept,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

     void
    on_accept(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "accept");

        // Read a message
        do_read();
    }

    void
    do_read()
    {

        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(
                buffer_,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_read,
                        shared_from_this()));
        cout<<"messaege from server" << boost::beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data()) <<endl;


    }

    void
    on_read(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        // This indicates that the session was closed
        if(ec == websocket::error::closed)
            return;

        if(ec)
            fail(ec, "read");

        // Echo the message
        ws_.text(ws_.got_text());

        HandleAsyncWrite();
       //     sleep(3);
    }

    void
    on_write(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Clear the buffer
        buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());
        write_buffer.consume(write_buffer.size());
        write_buffer.clear();

        // Do another read
       // do_read();
        m_sendQueue.pop_front();
        sleep(2);
        HandleAsyncWrite();

    }

    void HandleAsyncWrite()
    {

        contents = "message from server..." + std::to_string(duration_cast<seconds>((system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())).count()) ;
        size_t n = buffer_copy(write_buffer.prepare(contents.size()), boost::asio::buffer(contents));
        write_buffer.commit(n);
        bool write_in_progress = !m_sendQueue.empty();

        m_sendQueue.push_back(beast::buffers_to_string(write_buffer.data()));

        if (!write_in_progress)
        {

            ws_.async_write(
                    net::buffer(m_sendQueue.front()),
                    beast::bind_front_handler(
                            &session::on_write,
                            shared_from_this()));

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

        }
        else
        {
            //HandleError(ec);
            if (!m_sendQueue.empty())
                m_sendQueue.clear();
        }
    }


};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener>
{
    net::io_context& ioc_;
    boost::asio::io_context::strand strand{ioc_};
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

public:
    listener(
            net::io_context& ioc,
            tcp::endpoint endpoint)
            : ioc_(ioc)
            , acceptor_(ioc)
    {
        beast::error_code ec;

        // Open the acceptor
        acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "open");
            return;
        }

        // Allow address reuse
        acceptor_.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "set_option");
            return;
        }

        // Bind to the server address
        acceptor_.bind(endpoint, ec);
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "bind");
            return;
        }

        // Start listening for connections
        acceptor_.listen(
                net::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "listen");
            return;
        }
    }

    // Start accepting incoming connections
    void
    run()
    {
        do_accept();
    }
private:
    void
    do_accept()
    {
        // The new connection gets its own strand
        acceptor_.async_accept(
                net::make_strand(ioc_),
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &listener::on_accept,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
    {
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "accept");
        }
        else
        {
            // Create the session and run it
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket),strand)->run();
        }

        // Accept another connection
        do_accept();
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    auto const address = net::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1");
    auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi("6766"));
    auto const threads = std::max<int>(1, std::atoi("10"));

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc{threads};

    // Create and launch a listening port
    std::make_shared<listener>(ioc, tcp::endpoint{address, port})->run();

    // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    v.reserve(threads - 1);
    for(auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
        v.emplace_back(
                [&ioc]
                {
                    ioc.run();
                });
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Until it gets interuppted by client, the server should continue to send messages.
Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: FYI: WebSockets (unlike tcp/ip sockets) is a message based protocol, not a stream based protocol. By it's nature, you will have to divide the stream into messages.

Comment: @Myst Then is there a way to contineously write to client? this is my utimate goal. Because after one read/write operation it goes back to read again which is okay, but I want to send messages continously after some miliseconds.

Comment: I don't use Boost, but I imagine you could use either a timer to send data or a pub/sub approach / callback to send data (that's what I do with facil.io, which is a C library).

Comment: @Ayazawa I'm having same issue but from the client perspective. I wan't to listen to a  incoming feed from a server continuously until client or server closes connection. Have you found a solution to this? Because I can use the same solution but the reverse in the client side I assume.